# Which power cable should I use for a Macintosh 128K (upgraded to a Plus)

Tags: mac, power

I’ve just bought a Macintosh 128K, upgraded to a Macintosh Plus 1MB, and it didn’t come with a power cable. I’m told it needs a 110V kettle cable.

I’ve got a UK plug kettle cable which says “13A” on the fuse, but it says 1A on the back of the computer. Is this safe to use?

If not, which is the correct cable to use for this Mac?

Edit: on the plug it says 10A, 250V AC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it needs 110v then you need a power transformer, not just a kettle plug.

The plug known as a kettle plug often isn't one…
See the list of power couplers on WIkipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#Appliance_couplers - a 'kettle plug' is actually a high-temperature [C15] version of the more common IEC C13 plug.
You can buy IEC 13s just about anywhere - & many people have spares from old computers etc still kicking around in drawers.
The C15 has a notch to prevent plugging a 'low temperature' C13 into it. Plugging the other way, a high temp C15 into a low temp C14 appliance is no issue.

Your issue isn't the plug, it's the voltage.
If you plug a 110v Mac into a 240v supply, you will kill it, stone dead.

If you can get a photo of the appliance rating sticker on the back, then we can be more certain.
Modern computing/electronics has universal voltage, anything from 100v to 250v would be fine. Older devices may need specific voltages, with only perhaps 10% tolerance.

Comment: If it's a UK Mac, then chances are it's fine, though, surely?

Comment: @benwiggy - there's *should* & there's *bang*. ;) No-one said it was a UK Mac. It might be, but it might not be. It might also be universal voltage even from back then, but… it might not be. Seeing the spec sticker on the back would be the best confirmation. I found this, which, amongst some confusion, seems to think they may be switchable internally, but they're definitely not universal - https://68kmla.org/forums/topic/33097-from-110v-to-220v/

Comment: I seem to remember the old beige PowerMacs had a switch from one voltage to the other.